# Slideshow / Thumbnail on homepage not shows up on wordpress 3.4.2

Tags: image, wordpress, post, slideshow

I'm new to wordpress and currently I'm building a website using it.  But now I'm confused about why my post's image doesn't show up on the homepage's slideshow / featured post but it does show up in the post if I open that post.  I'm using Weekly Theme right now, but if I change to another theme it will return the same result too ( images won't show up ).  How to fix this?  Is there any specific codes I need to add or what?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard without being able to see what's going on. Do you have a link to the site? Or the place you got the theme from?

Is it just the image that won't show up in the slideshow/featured area? Or does the text not show up either?
- If it is just the image then you are probably not setting an image in the way the theme wants. Ensure the image is both "in" the article text and also set as the Featured Image using the box on the right-hand-side of the edit screen.

Comment: well the site is : [link](http://askjansen.co.cc)
The text is showing up but the image doesn't.  And it affects all themes even premium themes one.  How to fix that?

Comment: It looks like they are pulling the images from the Featured Image setting in a post. Have you set one for each of the posts you want to appear in the slider? See [here](http://i.minus.com/iVtEYQWpCXkTd.png) if you are not sure what this is.  
Otherwise - apparently your theme comes with a README.txt which should help, have you tried in there?